# Prisma model typing issue - expected non-nullable type "String", found incompatible value of "null"

Tags: postgresql, prisma

#### Problem

I am using Prisma as an ORM for a psql database. When I try to delete a row from a table (`Plant`) that my current table (`Pod`) references I get the error:

> Error converting field "plantId" of expected non-nullable type "String", found incompatible value of "null".

My intention is, when the underlying `Plant` row is deleted, the reference or foreign_key on the `Pod` rows that reference it, are set to `null`. However, I can't seem to set it up correctly. I thought by typing it with `plantId: String?` it would be able to handle that since the `?` set's the row to either `<type>|null`.

I could really use some help, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```js
// Plant
model Plant {
  id      Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  plantId String @unique @default(uuid())
  name    String @unique
  pods    Pod[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

// Pod
model Pod {
  id       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  podId    String  @unique @default(uuid())
  name     String  @db.VarChar(200)
  hasAlert Boolean
  plant    Plant?  @relation(fields: [plantId], references: [plantId], onDelete: SetNull)
  plantId  String?
  batch    Batch   @relation(fields: [batchId], references: [batchId], onDelete: Cascade)
  batchId  String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

#### Prisma Studio walk through:

`Pod` has a foreign key pointing to `Plant` (named broccoli)

[image]

In `Plant` table, I delete the referenced `Plant` (broccoli) that we saw in `Pod`

[image]

Upon returning to the `Pod` table, we get the following error:

[image]

Comment: I ran `npx prisma migrate dev reset` > `npx prisma migrate reset` > `npx prisma generate` and then re-launched my prisma studio and it was behaving correctly suddenly. Not sure where the issue came up. Though, I was reading this article in the docs and it was relevant so for future reference: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-actions

Comment: This happened to me after adding a new field to prisma schema. I'm using prisma with mongodb and my users collection had a new phone field added. Because phone was undefined for all existing documents I get  this error. I've fixed that by adding default value empty string:  phone   String   @unique @default("")

Comment: restarting the prisma studio worked just fine for me in new versions, I guess it was just prisma studio schema wasn't updated

Comment: @birajad please submit your answer. it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Under similar circumstances I had a value that is used as a key in a relationship to another entity. However I was trying to create data, not delete.

```
  latestSomethingId String  @unique @db.ObjectId
```

what solved the issue was making the fields optional (by adding ?). Hope is useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to screenshots your lines contains plantId but for some other users who face this issue it may be that you have some documents or lines in your database that does not contain that spesific field so when you requested it from database prisma can not convert non existing property into String(which is type of the attribute)